# How I prevent background image from reapet using mpdf with codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, mpdf

I am using the mPDF plugin in CodeIgniter. I intend to insert a background image to every page of a dynamically generated PDF document, but I want to prevent the background image from being repeated using `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

When I used the above CSS property, my image will become hidden.

Below are my codes:

```
<div style="width:800px; height:600px; background-image:url('<?php echo base_url('dashboard/img/backlog.png')?>') ; background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

Note: when I remove `background-repeat: no-repeat;` property, the background image will be shown and repeated.